# How to return limited array including mentioned item in Mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have Mongo-based service that supports *like*/*unlike* logic for forum posts. Here is a sample post document from DB (all post details are omitted):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("post_1"),
    ...
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : "user_1",
            "liked_at" : ISODate("2015-09-18T14:13:42.760Z")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "user_2",
            "liked_at" : ISODate("2015-09-18T14:13:42.760Z")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "user_3",
            "liked_at" : ISODate("2015-09-18T14:13:42.760Z")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "user_4",
            "liked_at" : ISODate("2015-09-18T14:13:42.760Z")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "user_5",
            "liked_at" : ISODate("2015-09-18T14:13:42.760Z")
        }
    ],
    "likes_number" : 5
}
```

So I need to write query that solves two tasks:

1. Limit **likes**-array to **N**, e.g. return 3 last likes with a post details.
2. Determine - does user like this post?

1st is simple - I'm using [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator for it:

```
db.posts.find(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("post_1")
    },
    {
        "likes" : {"$slice": -3}
    }
)
```

But I can't find solution for 2nd. I need to calculate any logical flag on condition

```
if likes-array contains like with user_id equal to user_1 - return true
```

Looks like Mongo can't do that.

Then I decided to return **N** last likes from 1st task and 1 requested like in addition. E.g. return 3 last likes and +1 like of **user_1** if he likes a post. Could anyone help me with this query or is it impossible to get necessary data in one operation in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering own question:

Said above task was solved by using additional field `liked_users`, it duplicates user identificators from some points of view but now I easily can:

1. Limit likes-array to N, e.g. return 3 last likes with a post details.
2. Determine - does user like this post

And Java side just calculate `isLiked()` based on length of `liked_users` array.

```
db.posts.find(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("post_1")
    },
    {
        "likes" : {"$slice": -3},
        "liked_users": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": "ANY_USER_ID"}}
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the $elemMath operator, e.g.

db.blog.find({_id:"post_1", likes:{$elemMatch:{"user_id":"user_7"}}},{_id:1})

Comment: unfortunately this query doesn't make any sense, I need to return last N likes and one requested (if exists) by one query. E.g. 3 last likes and like made by user_1